# How can I show a PDF in a browser when it has XFDF data?

Tags: html, pdf, xfdf

I need to show a PDF file with data, this data is a XFDF file. So the process works in my machine I open the XFDF and automatically the PDF appears with a data. 
The problem is when I make this process in a web environment, the HTML page does not show anything.

I have 2 files: the PDF is TestForm1.pdf and the XFDF is TestForm1.xfdf.

I can embed an empty PDF, and it works:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="TestForm1.pdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
```

But following (with the XFDF) does not work:

```
<object type="application/vnd.adobe.xfdf" data="TestForm1.xfdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
```

The code of my XFDF file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<f href="TestForm1.pdf"/>
<fields>
    <field name="Name_UeSd4O*CXTlIKGfP8CI1Lg">
        <value>Aaron</value>
    </field>
</fields>
<ids original="F76AE09E68036941A6318DF3754A9CD1" modified="4FB18F258D7B8F4699CCCF49538E852F"/>
</xfdf>
```

Please I need help or guide about this issue.
Regards.

Comment: http://dpastov.blogspot.com/2010/01/open-xfdf-file-in-browser-using-abobe.html

Comment: I tried this solution but It doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since you posted. Sorry to revive. Been working on this same issue.

Solve the problem by changing the href path in your XFDF file to the full server path that the pdf is located in. i.e. "http://google.com/my.pdf